# Overriding a Database object in application.conf to no-op in certain environments

Tags: playframework, typesafe-config, hocon

I am trying to setup an application that has multiple database connections (some for readonly and some for readwrite).

95% of the time I would like both to be configured and, as such, I've got the environment variables specified appropriately to allow this to be the case.

However, in a few environments, I would like to disable one of the database connection pools from being available and I cannot figure out how to do that other than to exclude that pool by default and, in the 95% of environments, specify it manually.

Here's what I have right now in my application.conf:

```
db.neo4j = {
    driver: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
    ...
}
```

Is there a way that I can run play so that when I do this: `./bin/run-app` that I can specify NOT to load that neo4j database connection?

I've tried all of the following to no avail:

```
./bin/run-app -Ddb.neo4j=null
./bin/run-app -Ddb.neo4j={}
./bin/run-app -Ddb.neo4j=None
```

Every time I run that, I get the error `neo4j has type STRING rather than OBJECT`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `.conf` files and specify exactly [which one to use when starting your application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file). Per instance:

```
./bin/run-app -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf
```

So, you can have a `conf` file that has all the configurations necessary and another one that does not configure `db.neo4j` at all. To avoid repetition, you can have a file that contains all the configuration (excluding `db.neo4j`) and then have another one that just includes the `db.neo4j`:

File `conf/prod.conf`:

```
include "application.conf"

db.neo4j = {
    driver: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
    ...
}
```

Comment: That makes sense and does what I would expect. I was hoping to be able to do it without lots of separate config files but it sounds like that is the best route to go. Thank you @marcospereira for the quick response.